# Debian: prevent particular file from being overwritten during package upgrade

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I understand that a package has two components: `config` and `data` files. During package upgrade (i.e. security upgrade) `data` files can be overwritten, but `config` files should always stay the same. Also `config` files are usually in `/etc` and `data` in `/usr`. Sometimes, however, the distinction is blurred.

In my case, I have modified the icon file for `Icedove` (Thunderbird):

```
/usr/share/applications/icedove.desktop
```

Now, every time there is a `Icedove` (Thunderbird) update, my changes get overwritten with the default file (even if it has not changed between updates).

Is there any way to prevent this particular file from being overwritten?

Setting it to immutable with `chattr +i icedove.desktop` is not a good idea, as it produces error during package upgrade.

Comment: @don_crissti Technically the correct location is `$XDG_DATA_HOME/applications/icedove.desktop`, although this usually defaults to the search path you mention. The [XDG Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) also provides a search path in `$XDG_DATA_DIRS` for system wide overrides. A more detailed explanation of how XDG Base Directories apply in this case is in [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157902/43779).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While [wurtel's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157896/43779) answers the question as phrased, considering the background in the question reveals that this is yet another case of a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

In this particular case, `/usr/share/applications/icedove.desktop` should not be modified in the first place, but a local configuration file which overrides the default configuration should be placed in a suitable location. Systems which are freedesktop.org-compliant conform to the [XDG Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html), the purpose of which is precisely to eliminate the need for modifying configurations files that are overwritten during package upgrades.

If the configuration is intended to be system-wide, the local `icedove.desktop` should be placed in the `applications` subdirectory for a search path preceding `/usr/share` in `$XDG_DATA_DIRS`. The value of this environment variable defaults to `/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/`, but the actual value varies between distributions. Because in this case the configuration is intended to be local the correct location is `/usr/local/share/applications/icedove.desktop`, although keep in mind that they may be distribution specific overrides in place which might have preference over configurations under `usr/local/share`.

On the other hand, if the configuration is indented to be user specific, the local `icedove.desktop` should be placed under `applications` in the location indicated by `$XDG_DATA_HOME`. This usually defaults to `$HOME/.local/share`, i.e. the location for the configuration file should be `$HOME/.local/share/applications/icedove.desktop`.

Answer (score 11):

You want the `dpkg-divert` utility.

```
dpkg-divert --divert /usr/share/applications/icedove.desktop.packaged --rename /usr/share/applications/icedove.desktop
```

Comment: This might help others: "Do not attempt to divert a file which is vitally important for the system's operation - when using dpkg-divert there is a time, after it has been diverted but before dpkg has installed the new version, when the file does not exist. " from https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-diversions.html