# Can I create a *super* super-user so that I can actually have a user that can deny permission to root?

Tags: permissions, sudo, users, root

I was thinking that it might be advantageous to have a user with permissions higher than the root user.

You see, I would like to keep all of the activities and *almost* all existing root user privileges exactly as they are now.

However, I would like the ability to deny privileges to root on an extremely isolated case by case basis.

One of the advantages of this would allow me to prevent certain unwanted files from being installed during updates. This is just an example of one possible advantage.

Because apt-get updates are run by root or with sudo privileges, apt-get has the ability to replace certain unwanted files during updates.

If I could deny these privileges to these individual particular files, I could set them as a simlink to `/dev/null` or possibly have a blank placeholder file that could have permissions that would deny the file from being replaced during the update.

Additionally, I can't help but be reminded about a line which was said in an interview with one of the Ubuntu creators when the guy said something about how users better trust "us" (referring to the Ubuntu devs) "because we have root" which was a reference to how system updates are performed with root permission.

Simply altering the installation procedure to say work around this problem is absolutely not what I am interested here. Now that my mind has a taste for the idea of having the power to deny root access, I would like to figure out a way to make this happen just for the sake of doing it.

I just thought about this and have not spent any time on the idea so far and I'm fairly confident that this could be figured out. However, I am curious to know if this has already been done or if this is possibly not a new idea or concept.

Basically, it seems like there should be some way to have a super super-user which would have permission beyond that of the system by only one degree.

---

Note: Although I feel the accepted answer fits the criteria the most, I really like the answer by @CR. also.

I would like to create an actual user higher on the tree (me) but I guess I'll just have to sit down one day when I have the time to figure it out.

Additionally, I'm not trying to pick on Ubuntu here; I wouldn't use it as my main distro if I felt negative about it.

Comment: What sort of files are you talking about and why? "_prevent certain unwanted files from being installed _" suggests the files don't (normally) exist, and you want to stop them doing so; but "_hat would deny the file from being replaced during the update._" suggests the files already exist (with, presumably desirable content) and you don't want new versions.

Comment: One option would be to have a post-install script that restored specified files to their pre-installation state (from safe copies) or removed specified files you don't want (although depending on the files involved, and why you want to prevent them being updated, it may be "too late").

Comment: A wild idea that came to mind -- not sure if it's feasible -- would be to write a device-driver that "shadows" files. Replace selected files with a device-file-reference to this driver -- reads from the device would return the shadowed file, but writes would be (silently) discarded. This should prevent _overwriting_ the file, but I'm not sure if / how you could make it survive unlinking the device entry.

Comment: Be aware that any method that prevents `apt` from (over)writing files might lead to an error, aborting the update process. `apt` will then refuse to do any updates or installations until the "problem" is solved.

Comment: This is related. It is not about a super-super user, but includes stuff about limiting root. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101263/what-are-the-different-ways-to-set-file-permissions-etc-on-gnu-linux

Comment: "Simply altering the installation procedure to say work around this problem is absolutely not what I am interested here." Maybe so, but it is generally the *correct* way to solve the problem as stated. Limiting root can be done (formally, root-in-userland is not the same level of access as kernel mode), and there are systems for accomplishing it, but it goes against the Unix philosophy and basic security principles. In general, once somebody has "partial" root, it is exceptionally difficult to blacklist off everything they might use to get "full" root. Prefer only giving root to trusted code.

Comment: On some ancient systems, there were a "super-root" named "security manager" or similar. This user didn't have access to anything, *but* it could change the rights of anybody, including root.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this sounds a lot like a "The compiler is broken!" type of problem. Are you sure that changing the way the root user and privilege system of Unix works would be the correct end in which to look for a solution for your issue?

Comment: I think `man 1 dpkg-divert` will help you greatly. `dpkg` (which does the actual package installation for apt) has a built-in way to allow the sysadmin to override packaged files.

Comment: You'd just be creating a new root-user but now under another name. Might as wel ask: how do I rename root?

Comment: @Kevin I think you are missing the point. I'm not interested in that because that is not the problem. I realize your logic here and I see this a lot but I really don't care about apt and I'm fully capable of working around apt issues myself. I started using linux because I like having absolute control over my system, now I want more control and more power. People may say this is not good from a security standpoint but if someone gets that far then I'm already pwned anyhow so what's the difference?

Comment: @Kevin Also, I think SELinux and AppArmor is probably the way to go here as I am really just looking for a way to restrict root and this would still allow me to do still do stuff manually. It's kind of like having a manual root and a system root; manual root has power over system root and I think I'm fine with that. However, it's much more simplified to set an immutable flag on the files which also gives me the power to deny permission to root processes while still allowing me to do stuff manually.

Comment: @mchid: root *is* full control.  That's the whole point of it.  In order to make it not have full control, you have to deny so many things that it no longer looks like root (e.g. no installing kernel modules, no mounting arbitrary devices, and so on).  If you don't want to run things as root, then don't run them as root.  Instead, hand out capabilities (except for all the [root-equivalent ones](https://lwn.net/Articles/486306/), don't bother with those) or run a daemon like [polkitd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit) that performs root operations on behalf of non-root processes.

Comment: @Kevin I realize I wrote a lot of stuff so let me quote "However, I would like the ability to deny privileges to root on an extremely isolated case by case basis.". So, I don't want to deny "so many things" but only a few.

Comment: @mchid: That's the problem: There are a large number of ways for programs to circumvent your restrictions.  Unless you blacklist all of those ways, any program you run as "restricted root" can still become full root whenever it wants.  So your whole scheme is nothing more than a charade of security theater.

Comment: @Kevin Well then, I guess I need a super-super user to simply deny root on a case by case basis that has ultimate power over all users, including root. So now we are back to square one, what's the point?

Comment: @mchid: That's called "the kernel."

Comment: @Kevin If you have an answer for me on how I can be this kernel user and how I would deny root access I would really like to upvote your answer.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Wouldn't "How can I block access to root on a case-by-case basis" be a better question?

Comment: @OldBunny2800 I kind of thought so myself but then Keven here convinced me otherwise.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The "user" you want is called LSM: Linux security module. The most well known are SELinux and AppArmor.

By this you can prevent certain binaries (and their child processes) from doing certain stuff (even if their UID is `root`). But you may allow these operations to `getty` and its child processes so that you can do it manually.

Comment: But if their UID is root can't they change the selinux permissions that prevent them access in the first place?

Comment: @curious_cat: Yes, of course you need to deny a "limited root" process the ability to change / raise its own permission!  The people that wrote SELinux thought of that already...

Comment: @curious_cat You can configure the LSMs so that it is completely impossible to change their configuration at run time. You have to reboot and give a kernel parameter in order to to that then.

Comment: Hello selinux meet rowhammer.

Comment: @Joshua If your copy of apt-get is using Rowhammer then you have bigger problems to worry about.

Comment: @HaukeLaging And that's under the assumption that someone who can boot the machine and alter the kernel already has the keys to the kingdom anyway?

Comment: @corsiKa First, you want to restrict the people who can boot the machine to people who are actually *at* the machine, because systems are vulnerable while they're booting. Triggering a reboot over the net is fine, but allowing control *as* it boots is not. Second, a rule of computer security is that you cannot do anything once an attacker has physical access, because then they may as well dunk everything in LN2/rewire the hardware/etc. So, yes, someone who can alter the booting of a machine is generally assumed to have "won" the machine.

Comment: @corsiKa That is a reasonable but in this case non-necessary assumption. It is enough to assume that it is impossible for anyone remote to influence the kernel parameters. Of course, the LSM has to protect the boot loader configuration, too, in this case.

Comment: So in  a way, unlike creating an user "above" root as the OP wanted this strategy creates an inferior version of the root user (process specific) that cannot do everything?

Comment: @curious_cat Yes, you could put it that way.

Comment: @corsiKa These days with UEFI etc. booting can be quite well protected too, right? I am just curious. Are we out of the dark ages when being in front of the machine at boot time meant you had the keys to the kingdom? Are BIOS passwords etc. still a joke?

Comment: @curious_cat> with physical access to the system you can do anything, including physically opening the hard drive and read/modify magnetic state on the plates directly, provided you have the required tools. Or flash the firmware with another of your choice. Or replace the CPU with one featuring a backdoor. Imagination and time are the only limits.

Comment: @spectras What if I full disc encryption to  encrypt the drives?  Reading magnetic state won't give you much? Flashing the firmware also won't help if the encryption keys are lost? CPU's with backdoors yes but I'm assuming the adversary is not capable enough. Cop out.

Comment: @curious_cat> Flashing system firmware is enough to open a backdoor. Full disc encryption has the drawback that you must give it the key, and having had physical access I can eavesdrop on that, whatever you use to that purpose.

Comment: @curious_cat> in more abstract words, once an attacker has had physical access to your system just once, you can no longer trust your hardware, ever. And all software solutions rely on the ability to trust at least some part of it. CPU, memory, PCI bus, …

Answer (score 50):

**You're misunderstanding the concept of the `root` user.**

In plain English, `root` is at the "top of the tree".

What if you decide one day to have a "super super user", and then next month, a "super super super user"(!). How far "up" the tree would you want to go? How would you shuffle all the permissions and hierarchy to make that work? Who is always at the top? Someone has to be at the top, and it's `root`. End of story.

The solutions given here - including AppArmor and SELinux - don't really change this. They simply allow finer grain control over `root` permissions and processes.

It sounds to me like your update process isn't suitable for the desired outcome. But that's not a fault of the `root` user, at all. Instead of overcomplicating things, think of `root` as the highest level permission user, and then everything else, you have to work downwards.

I know some people will mark this down, but there is no level higher in the user hierarchy, and all the other solutions simply give slightly different control to how `root` permissions work. But they do not *create* a new user, with higher permissions.

You can't have a user with "more permissions" than `root` because `root` represents the highest level of permissions possible. Using a phrase like "more control than root" is a contradiction - `root` has full control and all possible permissions, so there is nothing that can be done above it.

Comment: I would be at the top not root, end of story. Because there is no level higher in the user hierarchy is the exact reason I would like to create a higher user.

Comment: Although, that is kind of what I want: control over root permissions and processes so I can deny permission to root. If I can somehow deny permission to root without creating a new user with SELinux or AppArmor then I guess I don't need a new user. I want full control, more control than root.

Comment: You can't have a user that has "more permissions" than `root`. That's the whole problem. The user you are looking to create *is* essentially the root user. You need to approach this the other way, such as creating a user with `root` privileges, and then deny certain ones where you want finer control. What you're asking ("more control than root") isn't possible, or even a thing!

Comment: @mchid So what you actually want to do is rename the current root user to mchid, create a new user called root and make apt-get et al use your new, non-root user?

Comment: On some systems, `root` doesn't have permission to access hardware directly.  If you disable the loading of kernel modules, you can keep root locked out of total control over the hardware (`/dev/mem`, and stuff like that).  Not really relevant for filesystem permissions, since you wouldn't use an apt-get that talked to your SATA or NVMe controller directly...  But technically, there is a "more permissions than `root`" state, and it's called kernel mode. :P

Comment: This is actually the most correct answer.

Answer (score 26):

If you just want to prevent files or directories from being changed/deleted then just set the immutable flag on them.

```
chattr +i <file>
```

Not even root will be able to do anything to them unless the flag is removed. It's also possible to use the container/namespace system to prevent root access but that seems like overkill for what you need.

Comment: But root can remove the flag.

Comment: apt, like almost everything, will not use chattr to remove that flag.

Comment: @sebasth: Correct, but Apt, dpkg and per-package installation scripts won't (normally) alter file attributes. Instead they will just fail and complain when they try to alter files with the immutable flag.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Are the installation scripts likely to fail if they meet such a protected file? If so, this probably won't do what the OP wants (it sounds like they want the package to install _other than_ certain files).

Comment: @TripeHound So the OP wants `apt-get` to succeed in replacing the file, yet having that file intact? That's somewhat contradictory I dare say.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev It _sounds like_ they want `apt-get` to _think_ it succeeded but leaving one or more files unchanged. They don't say which files or why, but as you say, somewhat contradictory -- and prone to "odd behaviour" in the future.

Comment: immutable only works on certain file system types jffs2 being a notable exception.

Comment: [BSD securelevel](https://man.openbsd.org/securelevel.7) is also implemented in Linux, but you may need a proper *SystemV init* process that knows how to reset the securelevel when entering single-user mode. The general idea is that you need to be on the physical console to reset immutable/append-only flags, which is impossible for a network based attacker. The downside is that the init program itself and all the support scripts need to be immutable too, so you basically have to go singleuser for updates.

Comment: @TripeHound Here's a hack that comes to mind. What if we let apt change the files it wants but just have root keep a cron or similar watch on those files so that post the apt process we just silently replace all the offending files?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Actually, I expect apt to fail and I'm perfectly fine with that if it means that I can tell root what it can and can't do. I'm simply power-hungry.

Comment: @curious_cat: Even better, you can configure Apt to run arbitrary commands after every package installation. Such a command may invoke a shell script that restores the file(s) in question.

Comment: @sebasth I'm not worried about *someone* acting as root, I'm more interested in background processes running more indirectly as root like dpkg from apt-get as an example but not necessarily only that in particular.

Answer (score 9):

- Instead of having a super-super-user, you can limit root. see
  [What are the different ways to set file permissions etc on gnu/linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101263/what-are-the-different-ways-to-set-file-permissions-etc-on-gnu-linux)
- There is also AppArmor and SELinux.
- And/Or configure `sudo`, so that you do not give away full root privileges. You can set it up so that a user can only run pre-agreed commands, with pre-agreed arguments.
- You can also use virtualisation to restrict root:

  - cgroups, namespaces, chroot etc (docker does this)
  - Xen
  - Virtualbox
- See also `etckeeper`: this tool revision controls the `/etc` directory, and synchronises with apt. By default it is not secure, a malicious install could sabotage it, but you could also get it to push changes to a fire-walled backup repository.
- Use of revision control in general, with a fire-walled backup repository. This help with accidental, intentional corruption and hardware failure.

---

Firewalled backup repositories could be on a different machine, on the internet, or a different virtual machine (or host of virtual machine).

Answer (score 8):

For software like *APT*, which in normal operation require access to almost all of the system, restricting is problematic. Even if you prevent it from accessing certain parts of the system, there most likely are more than enough possibilities for malicious distributor to work around. For example by replacing a library or just a binary or adding a malicious configuration change, which unrestricted root is going to use eventually.

Depending on how much you would place restrictions, some install scripts can be expected to break.

For ways to restrict applications and users, you can write an AppArmor or a SELinux policy. Such policy would  Which is more supported depends on your distribution: Debian based have better support for AppArmor while Fedora/RHEL based distributions enable SELinux by default.

Both AppArmor and SELinux work on *white list* policies, which contain rules to allow (or deny) specific actions. Policies are applied to a process at *exec*, similarly users can be restricted when a policy is applied to their processes at log-in. A well thought policy can not be circumvented (if kernel bugs are not considered). Confined process running as root (uid 0) is restricted by the configured policy and cannot change it unless explicitly allowed in the policy.

AppArmor policy language defines a [*deny rule*](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/AppArmor_Core_Policy_Reference#deny), which can be used to build a *blacklist policy*. A good place to begin with AppArmor is AppArmor [man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man7/apparmor.7.html), [wiki](http://wiki.apparmor.net/) and looking the existing configuration on your distribution in `/etc/apparmor.d/`.

Plenty SELinux administration and development material is provided in [SELinux wiki](https://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page). SELinux [reference policy](https://github.com/TresysTechnology/refpolicy) is hosted on github.

Answer (score 7):

I can't believe no one has mentioned apt pinning...

A couple years ago, Microsoft released a patch that broke Windows 10 machines from talking to our old Samba NT4 Domain Controllers. When the issue was found, we pinned the Samba package to stay at the current version, and `apt` still functioned correctly.

A full [Debian Walkthrough](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) explains the process well:

In `/etc/apt/preferences` (or a new file under `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`), add some text to specify which package and version:

```
Package: samba
Pin: release v=3.6.6-6+deb7u7
Pin-Priority: 900
```

Check the documentation for the exact syntax, but this is the quick and dirty way we pinned a package version. Root *could* bypass it, as root can always do, but this solves the problem of package managers trying to automatically upgrade packages on you.

NOTE: This answer is assuming you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I have answered a number of XY problems myself on askubuntu. However, apt is just an example and is what lead me to the idea. I'm more interested in the "power-corrupts-and-absolute-power-corrupts-absolutely" aspect of the whole thing. Complete and absolute power over my own system is what lead me to linux in the first place. Realizing that my power is not always absolute over root is kind of unsettling; the idea of absolute power is enticing.

Comment: Also, I guess it is a bit of an XY problem but Y here is "how do I deny permission to root when root is the superuser?"

Comment: @mchid it's not about denying permissions to root, but denying something to a program running as root.

Answer (score 6):

It's actually quite simple.

Root is your "super super user"

Create an account called "admin" and give him all of root's permissions except the one's you don't want.

Then create a user called bob, and let him "become admin". By using su or even sudo.

Now you have a normal user (bob) a super user that can do admin stuff (admin) and a super super user (root).

If you want to change the name "root" to something else you can even do that. Technially only the user id (0) matters.

Comment: If I had a normal user (bob), a super user that can do admin stuff (admin), and a super super user (root), wouldn't root still be doing all the admin stuff with the background processes, cronjobs, and other stuff as user id (0)?

Comment: not if you don't want them to. Most services let you choose what user does the work. You could set it up so the admin user is the one running the processes. There are a few exceptions, but not many.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to go through and set all of those process individually?

Comment: That's what happens when you try to break the standard conventions. I think you need to better understand the hows and whys of the permissions systems in a *nix environment.

Comment: I agree with Shauna, you seem to lack a fundamental understanding of the *nix permission system. It's very powerful, but it's nothing like windows.

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is simply to prevent specific files from being installed, then restricting root permissions is not the way to go about doing this.  It is worth noting also that the conventional answers (immutable files or LSM's) will not work for your particular use case, as APT (and most other package managers), will bail out if they can't install files.

The real question you want to be asking is:

Is there a way to prevent APT from installing specific files?

That is something completely different from what you're asking on multiple levels.

Now, as to that question, I'm not 100% certain myself, but I do know a number of other package managers have options to prevent specific files from being installed (for example, Gentoo's Portage system has the option `INSTALL_MASK=`, which actually accepts shell-style matching patterns of things to not install).  I'd be more than willing to bet that such an option exists for APT ( or possibly dpkg itself).

Comment: Really, "Is there a way to prevent APT from installing specific files?" is not my question; this is just an example and what brought the question to my mind. The new firefox ships with addons and installs these files even after the user deletes them with new updates. This is not actually the problem; this is what made me realize that I want even more control over my system. I do, however, appreciate your logic here as I have answered a few questions this way myself so thanks for the input.

Comment: dpkg-divert does this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/157896/70847

Answer (score 1):

You could run a type-1 hypervisor like [Xen hypervisor](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjhl4bOrYrWAhVkqVQKHQJYBHAQFggxMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xenproject.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNHtF1sFas80yKM-C6deq6bPCP-iZQ) 
& have that hosting your regular OS as a virtualized guest. 
The hypervisor controls the virtual guest OS at a level "deeper" than root because it has control over the (virtual) hardware on which the guest OS runs.

You could program the hypervisor to manipulate the guest OS in various ways, including changing permissions, creating & applying backups, hooking certain changes or instructions in the guest OS to inject additional functionality, validation, etc. That would be a valid, potentially useful way to implement a unix type system with a "user" (actually a function of the hypervisor) for "doing things even root cannot do"

My sense that this approach is probably overkill though

Comment: How does a hypervisor prevent a user with root permission from doing anything they wish to do in a guest VM?

Comment: This answer starts ok, but then grammatically goes astray (it is then reading the wrong way around, or at least ambigues). I did a fix.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 a hypervisor can hook system calls, apply policies, etc. to enforce arbitrary restrictions on root user or any other part of the guest OS. Maybe my answer isn't good because this is way too much work unless you've got some real enterprise use case or something though...

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Thanks for your fix, but I don't think grammar was the problem. I clarified what I meant to say though, & I appreciate the feedback that my thoughts weren't clear at first

Comment: @NathanSmith. I am curious,  please name one existing commercially available hypervisor that provides the ability "to enforce arbitrary restrictions on root user"

Comment: hypervisor can by definition change anything about the system state. whether existing commercial tools provide a reasonable way to do achieve OP's goals using a hypervisor is another question & a claim I don't feel qualified to make

Comment: @fpmurphy1 virtualbox, docker, xen … Root in side a guest system, can-be / is restricted and has much less abilities than in the host.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor.  Let\s take VirtualBox as an example since you mentioned it. I install a Linux guest.  How does VirtualBox give me the ability to restrict what the guest's root user does within the guest VM?

Comment: @fpmurphy1 within the guest you have full root. However it is not the same root as root on the host. Therefore it is a lesser root than the host root. Docker will allow things to be more integrated, but still put restrictions on root.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 “let us” is abbreviated to “let's”, not “let\s”.

Comment: @fpmurphy1 Virtualbox is an open source project. Assuming it does not support applying the kind of controls & restrictions we're talking about, you're welcome to code it in yourself. If you're not up to that kind of task, what makes you think that you're going to improve anything by messing with the fundamental permissions model of your OS? I know I wouldn't...

Answer (score 1):

Put a backup copy in a safe place.  After any install/update, immediately replace the specific files from that back-up.  Thus, no errors to screw up the install but you still get back the file(s)  you wanted to keep.

Answer (score 1):

## Work from a mounted drive

Note that this mostly a conceptual answer, but I think it should work and be in spirit with what you want to achieve.

Let system X be your working system, and system Y an other system which you control

1. Mount a directory from Y as a drive in X
2. Set up the rights in such a way that the root user of X has rights on everything in this mounted drive, with a few exceptions

Now you have your 'working root' which can do nearly everything, and you have your 'super root', the actual root account of system Y, which can truely do everything.

Comment: I like the idea, although, I would like to do this on a running system.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [cgroups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups) and [Linux namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_namespaces) as an alternative method of achieving this type of goal, as well as tools based on them like [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) and [lxd](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/).

These tools allow you to, among other things, limit what parts of the file system a process running as "root" can see, limit which processes are visible to it, and provide only certain [capabilities](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/security/linux-privs/kernel-2.2/capfaq-0.2.txt) to the "root" user.

Answer (score 0):

## UNINSTALL `sudo`

How about uninstalling `sudo` and symlink `/bin/su` to `/bin/false`? Couple that with making sure that `root` cannot login via `ssh` and you have locked down the system.

That makes `root` the Super*Super User, and everyone else is subordinate to that.

For files replaced during updates, simply do not do any updates. More realistically, change the permissions of the files to `440` or `444` so they can't be written. Or put them in a git repository so if they do get overwritten, it can be reverted.

Comment: You see, I still want to do updates and I still want root doing pretty much all the stuff that root normally does. However, I want to be able to say to root "hey don't do that" or "no, you can't do that" like a parental authority would be able to do to an offspring. As it is now, Root is like the parental authority on my system and all the little children say "mother may I?" when they use sudo. This is fine. However, almost every person on this planet is an offspring of somebody. It seems like some answers here are like a toddler would be at before self awareness when they don't realize

Comment: . . . that grandma and grandpa are the mothers and fathers of mom and dad. I would like to ask grandpa to come live in my system because, right now, root is the Dad of the house and Grandpa can tell Dad what to do because Grandpa is Dad's father :)

Comment: It sounds like you have added too many people with sudo powers. Adjust the `sudoers` file so only selected users can sudo to pre-selected commands.

Comment: I only have two users in the sudoers file including root. I was trying to use a simile to explain how some people seem to not understand my question and what I would like to achieve.

Comment: It seems like people feel like there can not be any user higher than root in the same way that a very young child feels that their mom and dad can have no parent. Also, I did not downvote.