# User with nearly all admin permissions but not allowed stop a single app or to delete its relevant files

Tags: permissions, osx

How can I create a user on macos who has nearly all permissions of admin user, but is not able to stop a binary whitelisting/blacklisting system (https://github.com/google/santa) from execution nor is able to delete its relevant files?
So on the bottom line it's an admin who can't stop the application controll app itself.

Should this user be able to user permissions? Yes

Should this user be able to edit their own permissions? No

Should this user be able to create new users? No

Should this user be able to create new, unrestricted admin users? No

Should this user be able to create setuid 0 binaries? No

Should this user be able to edit the whitelist? No

Comment: Should this user be able to user permissions? Should this user be able to edit their *own* permissions? Should this user be able to create new users? Should this user be able to create new, unrestricted admin users? Should this user be able to create setuid 0 binaries? Should this user be able to edit the whitelist? TL;DR: you need to think about your requirements a lot more.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed comment! I edited my question according to it.

Comment: Unfortunately, they are just the most obvious ways I could think of to subvert this scheme. There are many, many more.

Comment: unfortunately I am not savvy enough to oversee the possibilities of subversion

Comment: Related: [Can I create a \*super\* super-user so that I can actually have a user that can deny permission to root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/390135/80216)